# Benchmark object method to get delta

Tags: perl, benchmarking, accessor

I'm timing the execution time of a webservice with [Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html).

```
use strict; use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Benchmark qw(:hireswallclock);

my $t0 = Benchmark->new;
1 for (1..10000000); # webservice request goes here
my $t1 = Benchmark->new;
my $td = timediff($t1, $t0);
say 'Code took ' . timestr($td);
```

This says:

> Code took 0.433091 wallclock secs ( 0.42 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.42 CPU)

Since I'd like to know how fast the webservice reacts to different input values, this will go into a loop. I'd like to save just the delta (`0.433091`) in an array so I can calculate the average later.

Perldoc says about `timediff`:

> Returns the difference between two Benchmark times as a Benchmark object suitable for passing to timestr().

So I'm thinking there must be some more methods, mustn't there?

I've thought of two ways to get that number:

1. Use a regex:

   ```
   timestr($td) =~ m/([\d\.]+) /;
   say $1;
   ```
2. Access it directly:

   ```
   use Data::Dumper;
   print Dumper $td;
   ```

   This yields:

   ```
   $VAR1 = bless( [
                    '0.433090925216675',
                    '0.422',
                    '0',
                    0,
                    0,
                    0
                  ], 'Benchmark' );
   ```

   So I could just:

   ```
   say $td->[0];
   ```

The first method seems like the easy way, but I don't like it.

The second method seems very unsafe. It's never a good idea to access object data directly. Surely there must be an accessor method for this.

What are your suggestions? Does anyone know about an accessor for this `Benchmark` object? Or should I do this differently? Which way would you use?

Comment: As benchmarks don't make it into production code I do not think direct access is "very unsafe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you are right to avoid looking at the object's private parts.

The class actually provides an accessor for getting that number:

```
say $td->real;
```